# Discharging 18650 at higher Peak-Amperage than rated max continuous Amperage?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, discharge

I am using Sanyo NCR18650BL cells. They are rated for 7A max continuous discharge, but i could not find any info on temporarily discharging them at a higher rate (for example 10A per cell). Is it acceptable to discharge a cell (during a very short period of time for example 1 minute) at a higher peak amperage than the rated continuous max amperage? (provided the battery pack temperature is being monitored via the bms and as soon as temperature gets over for example 70 celcius the bms cuts the power or more likely limits the power to  for example 7A per cell).
Or is it a bad idea and a no-go to discharge any cell (even temporarily) above rated continuous max amperage?

cell info: http://www.nkon.nl/sk/k/NCR18650BL-specification.pdf

Could you give me an indication of how bad the effect on cell life/capacity would be caused by this temporary higher discharge rate?

My bms can handle 200A but is adjustable (via bluetooth), can adjust max amperage adjusting to current temperature.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use this type of cell? Exceeding the datasheet‘s parameters (1 minute is not a short amount of time) will lead to accelerated degradation in several characteristics and might be safety critical. 
Better choose a cell suitable for your application or add some cells in parallel to split the current further.

Comment: If it was OK the datasheet would probably say so : datasheet for many similar cells will list a higher short term or peak discharge rate.  That cell has quite a high capacitty for an 18650 : makes me wonder if they have optimised capacity at the expense of other parameters ... like discharge rate. If you need 10A in may be the wrong cell for the job.

Comment: @thauer  no particular reason other than that I have a lot of them currently (my 200cell battery pack consists of these cells) (and also the high capacity is quite nice).. if I were to go for a different cell in the future is there any that you would recommend which could handle 15A continuous?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But maybe you are able to reduce the peak current in your application if you already have all those batteries.

Comment: @Thauer yes I agree it will be best to limit the Amps to ensure battery health/longevity. I will limit the power user either the BMS or the BLDC controller. thank yo for your input!